# Compressing folder without using additional space on the drive

Tags: compression, zip, io

I have an 18GB EC2 instance that has run out of space. I wanted to zip and transfer files off the server to a local drive. There is just about 1% free space remaining on it. This means that I cannot compress anything on the drive because it keeps giving me `zip I/O error: No space left on device` error. Is there a way I can compress everything without using additional drive space?

Comment: You need some drive space to write the first compressed file(s), while you still have the original file(s). But you can write to another drive, for example a USB pendrive.

Comment: @sudodus Are you saying I can compress an EC2 folder to a flash drive connected to my Mac?

Comment: I have no Mac computer, so I don't know, but it should work on a pc. Depending on the size of the folder (to be compressed) and the size of the flash drive, you might succeed directly, or you may have to compress only part of the folder in a first step. Then *after checking that the compression was successful*, you can remove the original files.

Comment: What operating system are you running (distro and version, for example Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS)?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: 1. Are you running Ubuntu only on the the server or also on the Mac? 2. Is there a USB port on the server, that you can use? 3. If you are running MacOS on the Mac, can you boot a live Ubuntu session from a USB pendrive or DVD disk? 4. Do you know `rsync` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a command to compress to stdout over ssh and redirect stdout localy to a file. Something like:

```
ssh user@host "tar c /mydir | gzip -f" > myarchive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Tried this on Windows 10, but it created corrupted file and twice the expected size. Had to use [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) for that. It was much faster and no problems with extraction. Though I couldn't find a way to exclude some folders. `"tar c --exclude='./var/cache' /path/to/myapp | gzip -f"` didn't work. Is there a way to exclude dirs in this approach?

Comment: @Sharak, your command looks fine to me but I might be overlooking something. Have you verified that the tar command works fine when you login to the remote machine and enter the command on the terminal? If you need more help I recommend you post your own question as more people will see it.

Comment: Yes, I confirm specifying related path doesn't work here. It has to be full eg. `ssh user@host "tar c --exclude='/home/ubuntu/www/example.com/var/cache/*' /home/ubuntu/www/example.com | gzip -f" > example.tar.gz`. This will include cache folder, but will skip all its conntent. As for that bug on Windows it looks like [PowerShell is at fault](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34839#issuecomment-541228872)

Answer (score 1):

The following tools are available in Ubuntu, and I have checked that `rsync`, `gzip` and `tar` are also available in MacOS.

- `rsync` which can copy files and/or directory trees locally and via a network
- `gzip` which compresses single files
- `tar` which can create an archive with many files and directory trees, and compress, if you specify it

### Change directory

Change directory with

```
cd path-to-source-directory
```

to the directory that you want to compress.

### `rsync`

> I don’t have physical access to the server. I always communicate via
>   ssh. I’ll look up rsync. Thanks.

`rsync` is a powerful copy tool, and it has a [built-in check, that the transfer is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/does-rsync-verify-files-copied-between-two-local-drives).

- It can copy files and/or directory trees locally and via a network
- It is often used for backup

  - locally to an external drive or
  - via a network connection to a server or between servers

It is straightforward to use `rsync`, if you have Ubuntu at both ends of the connection, and I checked that there is an `rsync` version also in MacOS.

I like the following command line where the option

- `-H` takes hard links into account (and avoids double transfers/copies); if there are no hard links, you should remove this option.
- `-a` 'archive' makes a copy that suits backup or synchronizing
- `-v` 'verbose' creates output of all files to be copied with `-n` and all files copied in the real case (without `-n`)
- `-n` makes it a 'dry run', just showing what it 'wants to do'

  ```
  rsync -Havn source/ target
  ```

In your case the source is in the server, and you run via the `ssh` connection. So, in the client (your Mac computer), run

```
rsync -avn user-id@ip-address:/path-to-source-directory/ path-to-target-directory
```

Please notice the trailing slash after the source directory.

If it looks good, you can let it do the transfer with the following command (remove the `n` for 'dry run')

```
rsync -av user-id@ip-address:/path-to-source-directory/ path-to-target-directory
```

### Tips and comments

- *After the transfer*, you can do what you want with the copy in the target directory. I think you want to compress it, and I suggest that you use **`tar`** for that purpose and create a tarball.
- If you cannot run `rsync` or `gzip` or `tar` in your MacOS, you can boot your Mac computer from a USB pendrive or DVD disk with Ubuntu, and run the programs that way. (The advice to boot the computer from a USB pendrive or DVD disk with Ubuntu applies also to a computer with Windows.)
- You can read the built-in manual **`man rsync`**, **`man gzip`** and **`man tar`** in your Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am sure that you can find good tutorials via the internet.

### `gzip`

Change directory with `cd path-to-source-directory` to the directory that you want to compress.

Compress single files with

```
gzip -c file > path-to-external-directory/file.gz
```

Change directory to where you want to extract the file and run gunzip to uncompress

```
cd to-where-you-want-to-extract-the-files
gunzip -c path-to-external-directory/file.gz > file
```

### `tar`

Change directory with `cd path-to-source-directory` to the directory that you want to compress.

Compress a group of files to a 'tarball', for example

```
tar -cvzf path-to-external-directory/file.tar.gz file1 file2 file3
```

or if there is space enough in the target partition on the external drive for the whole directory

```
tar -cvzf path-to-external-directory/file.tar.gz .
```

The space and final dot are important.

You can 'look into' the tar file with the command

```
tar -tvf path-to-external-directory/file.tar.gz
```

Extract the compressed files from the tarball with the following commands

```
cd to-where-you-want-to-extract-the-files
tar -xvf path-to-external-directory/file.tar.gz
```

Comment: My `path-to-external-directory` is on my local machine. The `path-to-source-directory` is on the server. With gzip, I would then run it from the server and specify the local machine path? How would gzip know where my local machine is?

Comment: 1. Is there a USB port (that you can use) on the server? In that case you can do it in the server. 2. Can you communicate via `ssh`? In that case you can transfer the files (or whole directory trees) via `rsync` and later on compress locally in the Mac.

Comment: I don’t have physical access to the server. I always communicate via ssh. I’ll look up rsync. Thanks.

Comment: @electrophile, It's a good idea to learn about `rsync` :-) I use it a lot. It is a powerful copy tool, that works both locally and via network connections. You can read the built-in manual **`man rsync`** in your Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am sure that you can find good tutorials via the internet. -- I will add a paragraph about `rsync` in my answer.